# How can I extract metrics (code churn metric) on the variation of the code of two software versions?

Tags: repository, code-metrics, codecharge

I'm a little confused. I would like to extract the metrics related to different versions of a software (source code) exists, which take into account the different modifications in the two versions of the software. 
I would like to understand how I can do this using GitHub or TortoiseSVN. I have to create two different repositories? Once you have created two repositories for the two versions of the software how do I proceed?

Comment: To clarify - are you using CodeCharge Studio, and wishing to see how much has changed between versions of the generated code?

Comment: Yes, I would like to see how much has changed the code between two versions, and I would extract code churn metrics. I'm a beginner in the Code Change analysis and this is the first time I've head of CodeCharge Studio. I don't now if it is better to use Code Studio instead of repository analysis tools. 
I do not necessarily need to use the repository.

Comment: codecharge vs codechange - I suspect CodeCharge Studio won't give you what you want - it is a rapid-web-development tool that generates code for websites using database settings and a visual IDE. If you are interested in analysis of how the code changes, then CCStudio won't help you there.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I'm going to try it.